# Creating a single executable .exe from Python script that uses PuLP

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, cx-freeze, pulp

I have been struggling with this for a while. I have used py2exe and cx_freeze to package everything. I am using a 32 bit machine and Everything works fine and the interface opens up and everything just that I know the entire puLP package is not being copied correctly into the package.  I know this because the solver does not work.  Inside both library zips in the packages created by py2exe and cx_freeze, there are only .pyc files included where PuLP has cbc.exe and other file types that make the solver work.

Is there any work around this? I have tried copying the actual PuLP package into the library.zip as well as into the dist folder and that didn't work.

Here is the setup I used for py2exe:
    import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

```
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["pulp"], 
                    "icon": "icon.ico",
                    "include_files": ["icon.ico","cbc.exe","cbc-32","cbc-64","cbc-osx-64","CoinMP.dll"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "my_app",
        version = "0.1",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("my_app.py", base=base)])
```

I received the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1470, in __call__
  File "my_app.py", line 796, in <lambda>
  File "my_app.py", line 467, in branchAndBound
  File "pulp\pulp.pyc", line 1619, in solve
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

**EDIT**
I tried to change the paths to cbc.exe and CoinMP.dll but that didn't really work either. I am probably missing something.

I changed the following inside solvers.py in the PuLP package:

```
try:
    coinMP_path = config.get("locations", "CoinMPPath").split(', ')
except configparser.Error:
    coinMP_path = ['/Users/al/Desktop/my_app/build/exe.win32-2.7']

try:
    cbc_path = config.get("locations", "CbcPath")
except configparser.Error:
    cbc_path = '/Users/al/Desktop/my_app/build/exe.win32-2.7'

try:
    pulp_cbc_path = config.get("locations", "PulpCbcPath")
except configparser.Error:
    pulp_cbc_path = '/Users/al/Desktop/my_app/build/exe.win32-2.7'
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Exe files inside library.zip won't work. You'll probably need to place them in the dist folder (there's an `include_files` option for cx_Freeze), and then configure PuLP to look for them in the right place.

Comment: I did do that with cx_freeze but I just didn't know where to configure PuLP. How do I configure PuLP?(I am pretty much a newbie to this)

Comment: I added some more details above

Comment: It [looks](https://code.google.com/p/pulp-or/source/browse/src/pulp/solvers.py#57) like you can write a config file with those locations, and call `pulp.solvers.initialize()` with the path to your config file. For how to build the paths, see [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the cx_Freeze docs.

Comment: have you solved this problem? Encounter the same problem...